# Are there more cards like Boseiju, Who Shelters All for non-mana costs?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Mana gained from [Boseiju, Who Shelters All](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Boseiju%2C%20Who%20Shelters%20All) and [Hall of the Bandit Lord](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Hall%20of%20the%20Bandit%20Lord) grant an ability to various spell types if it's used to pay for them. Are there similar, ability-granting effects for non-mana costs? I don't mean things like Devour, Devour is an ability that has nothing to do with costs; I ask specifically about costs in the rules sense.

Comment: I am guessing you are referring to additional costs (e.g. "as an additional cost to cast ~, sacrifice a creature")?

Comment: @Patters No if you read the ability of Boseiju it sais pay 2 life: gain 1 mana if that mana is spent on an instant or sorcery it can't be countered. Likewise Hall will say pay 3 life: gain 1 mana if that mana is spent on creature spell it gains haste

Comment: This would be a lot clearer if you gave an example of the kind of thing you're talking about. I don't really see how there can be an exact analogy for a non-mana cost. While the same mana could be used to pay for any mana cost, the same action can't generally be used on an arbitrary non-mana cost. Are you looking for something in the direction of "{T}: the next time you sacrifice a creature as a cost to cast a spell, that spell can't be countered."? Or just something like "{non-mana cost}: cast a spell without paying its cost. That spell can't be countered."?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you mean something like [Quicken](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Quicken) or [Savage Summoning](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Savage%20Summoning)?

Answer (score 1):

[No](http://magiccards.info/query?q=o%3A%22mana+is+spent%22&v=card&s=cname).

For stuff that modifies spells more generally, search for ["that spell"](http://magiccards.info/query?q=o%3A%22that+spell%22&v=card&s=cname) and ["those spells"](http://magiccards.info/query?q=o%3A%22those+spells%22&v=card&s=cname). You could also search ["target spell"](http://magiccards.info/query?q=o%3A%22target+spell%22&v=card&s=cname), but that's mostly going to turn up counterspells.

Comment: A rather blanket negative, when Cavern of Souls achieves the same result as Boseiju for creature spells, yet doesn't meet the strict templating in your first link.

Comment: @Brian S, Cavern of Souls doesn't "grant an ability to a spell", and the answer a looser template just in case.

Comment: Neither does Boseiju

Comment: @Brian S, LOL! Boseiju is the very example that defines what that means! Please read the question.

Comment: You appear to be correct; OP isn't actually asking for cards similar to Boseiju/Cavern, but ways to modify spells _other than_ spending special mana.

Comment: Searching for "spend this mana" would be another avenue with very similar templating, however that too yields only Cavern of Soul style effects: they decide what you can spend the mana on, but they do not confer any bonuses to what you spend the mana on like Boseiju and Hall do.